# MockWS with dynamic url

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to parse dynamic url into case url of MockWS like this

```
    val ws = MockWS {
      case ("POST", mockServer.getUrl + "/predict-nationality") =>
        Action {
          Ok(Json.obj(
            "ARE" -> 0.0015790796301290394,
            "ARG" -> 0.0015750796301290393,
            "AUS" -> 0.027795471251010895
          ))
        }
    }
```

However, I got error saying that **stable identifier required**. Only String without any modification is accepted there. But I really need to use **mockServer.getUrl + "/predict-nationality"** as url in this case. I also can't define it as val because of the MockWS {} scope.

How can I deal with this? any other ways to use MockWS with dynamic url? or if this can be solved with play framework or anything, I'm happy to do so too. It just that I want to mock ws request and response (written in scala)

Comment: Why do you need dynamic URLs? You should have full control over the URL used in your test, isn't it?

Comment: Though I don't see why you cannot use a `val` anyway. Can you share the code you tried?

Comment: @GaëlJ I can't declare new val for url inside MockWS {} scope, and also val declared outside MockWS {} scope cannot be used as well.

Comment: val x = mockServerUrl + "/predict-nationality"
    val ws = MockWS {
      case ("POST", x) =>
        Action {
          Ok(Json.obj(
            "ARE" -> 0.0015790796301290394,
            "ARG" -> 0.0015750796301290393,
            "AUS" -> 0.027795471251010895
          ))
        }
    } Here x is unknown in {}